# How to create a custom module in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image]

I want to create a custom mode for my WooCcommerce orders. The following field which I have marked is the custom order field which I have added.

What I want to do is I want a module that tell me the commission due for each worker. If worker serves orders < 500 then the commission is 10% on his per day sales. If If worker serves orders > 500 then the commission is 20% on his per day sales.

I want to create such module, I know PHP but I do not know who can I get the the "served by" from each order and create such module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concrete query is probably depending on how implemented the field but here's what I'd write:

```
function served_orders($worker, $date, $options=array()) {
  return new WP_Query(array_merge(array(
    'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'meta_query' => array('key' => 'server', 'value' => $worker),
    'date_query' => array(
      array(
        'year'  => $date['year'],
        'month' => $date['mon'],
        'day'   => $date['mday'],
      ),
    ),
  ), $options));
}

function commission_rate($worker) {
  return served_orders($worker, getdate())->count() > 500 ? 0.2 : 0.1;
}
```

Comment: I am really sorry but I a noob to wordpress, your query make sense to me but the question is where should i put this. The custom filed tha i have added in my order is actually additional field which has a name "additional_servedby" . I have created the field using a plugin in name " 
Woo Checkout Field Editor Pro" and displayed that field with the following code

Comment: /**
 * Display field value on the order edit page
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){

    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Served By').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'additional_servedby', true ) . '</p>';

}

Comment: @SyedFahadKhalid you can simply put the code in `functions.php`, or do a simple plugin (create `commission.php` inside `wp-content/plugins` folder with [plugin header comment](https://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header#Plugin_File_Header_Example) and the code).

Comment: But this is only showing me 0.1 or 0.2, plus it is not working properly. 
The commission is based up on the daily sale. Like, if Worker 1 does the sale > 500 so his commission is the 20% of that sale.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you know PHP. StackOverflow is a QA site, I'm not here to do your job/homework. Please use your brain and try to adapt to your situation (.i.e: 0.1 = 10%, 0.2 = 20%, the commission for each sale can be calculated by multiply the total with 0.1 or 0.2).

Comment: Yeah but your query is not working properly, worker 1 served 3000 of sales a day it is still giving me 0.1.

Comment: Hm, can you give me the raw output of the query?

Comment: Why have you used **$worker** in   'meta_query' => array('key' => 'server', 'value' => $worker), ins't it is uspposed to be $user ?

Comment: and the commission is based about the amount of sales. Here you are only counting the number of order. I want to Sum the total amount of per day orders of respective worker

Comment: Tell me what meta is used to get the total amount of each order

Comment: About `$worker`: I initially wrote it as `$user`, but that's not clear and can be confused with the viewing user so I changed it to `$worker`. To get the total, it is clearly stated in WooCommerce's doc: `WC()->order_factory->get_order($post_id)->get_total()`

Comment: Thanks alot you really helped me out. I might ask you something more again.